# Rails rspec - how to check for presence of some attributes in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, model

I have start learning ruby/rails few weeks ago. I have to write test case for a model class to verify if some crucial attributes are present are not.

```
RSpec.describe SomeModel, :type => :model do
  subject { SomeModel }

  it "should contain attributes" do
    expect(SomeModel.attributes).to include :uid
    expect(SomeModel.attributes).to include :isOkUser
    expect(SomeModel.attributes).to include :helperAIds
    expect(SomeModel.attributes).to include :lastRunTimePC
 end
end
```

The above snippet works, but I'm not sure it is the best way to do this.
Would like others suggestions on how to make this better.

Comment: should be fine. the question you want to ask yourself is: why are the attributes critical? if they really are where are the tests that actually exercise the model and by extension use those attributes?

Comment: @Mircea It's the attributes that are heavily used by other services in the application. The whole thing is undergoing lots of iterations and few people editing this stuff. But anyway thought these are a good starting point.

Comment: if you want to know if someone messes with these sure. the point is that if you have tests, your tests will break even without this check.

Comment: Is it OK to have the attribute `lastRunTimePC` yet for its value to be `nil`? Maybe you need to check what those attributes evaluate to rather than just checking the model has the capacity to store them?